# pass the data on the clipboard to a variable in Chrome Browser JS

Tags: javascript, clipboard

i want to create a chrome extension that read what's currently on the clipboard.
i tried the Chrome Clipboard API, but it didn't work for me.

```js
var clipboardData = navigator.clipboard.readText('text');
alert(clipboardData);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`readText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText) returns a Promise. You have to wait for it to resolve:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function (clipboardData) {
  alert(clipboardData);
});
```

Comment: it didn't work [ Uncaught (in promise) : undefined ]

Comment: Append a `catch` to the chain to see what the error is: `.then(...).catch(function (e) { console.error(e); });`

Comment: this is the error undefined
(anonymous) @ script.js:17
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ script.js:17